# Parse batch of SequenceExample

Tags: parsing, tensorflow, buffering, bufferedstrategy

There is function to parse SequenceExample --> tf.parse_single_sequence_example().

But it parses only single SequenceExample, which is not effective.

Is there any possibility to parse a batch of SequenceExamples?

tf.parse_example can parse many Examples.
Documentation for tf.parse_example contain a little info about SequenceExample:

> Each FixedLenSequenceFeature df maps to a Tensor of the specified type (or tf.float32 if not specified) and shape (serialized.size(), None) + df.shape. All examples in serialized will be padded with default_value along the second dimension.

But it is not clear, how to do that. Have not found any examples in google.

Is it possible to parse many SequenceExamples using parse_example() or may be other function exists?

Edit:
Where can I ask question to tensorflow developers: does they plan to implement parse function for multiple SequenceExample -s?

Any help ll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many small sequences where batching at this stage is important, I would recommend `VarLenFeature`s or `FixedLenSequenceFeature`s with regular `Example` protos (which, as you note, can be parsed in batches with `parse_example`). For examples of this, see the [unit tests associated with example parsing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/parsing_ops_test.py#L248) (testSerializedContainingSparse parses `Example`s with `FixedLenSequenceFeature`s).

`SequenceExample`s are more geared toward cases where there is significant amounts of preprocessing work to be done for each `SequenceExample` (which can be done in parallel with queues). `parse_example` does does not support `SequenceExample`s.

Comment: Unfortunately the inputs are SequenceExample -s. So I cant use parse_example().

Comment: You can certainly parse them in parallel with queues. Other than that, you could re-encode them as regular Examples as a workaround, or open a feature request (although the output of batched SequenceExamples seems a bit too complicated to make much sense) and/or a pull request.